# Mongo DB update issue error code 28, "cannot create field"

Tags: java, mongodb

`I am trying to update dynamic fields inside mongoDB collection , but it is giving error
but getting error "Cannot create field 'price' in element {newDataList: [ { link: "/products/deepak-test", price: 123.45, prid: "123456789", product_type: "Indoor", quantity: 1.0, shipping: "true", title: "Deepak Test" } ]}', details={ }}].
at com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.getError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:176)
"

code :
Document findQuery = new Document("siteId", siteId).append("prid", prid);

LinkedTreeMap<String,Object> newDatamap = (LinkedTreeMap) productList.get("new_data");

```
             for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : newDatamap.entrySet()) {
                activityDocument.put("newDataList."+entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
            }


            update = new Document("$set", activityDocument);

            UpdateOneModel<Document> updateOneModel = new UpdateOneModel<>(findQuery, update);

            mongoBatcher.insert((Integer.parseInt(clientId)), cmapDetails[0], "productCatalouge", cmapDetails[2], updateOneModel, this.requestId);
```

code :
" LinkedTreeMap<String,Object> newDatamap = (LinkedTreeMap) productList.get("new_data");

```
 db.productCatalouge.find({"prid":"123456789"})
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("651fb0e0cfee1daa261083db"),
    prid: '123456789',
    siteId: '910fb5db4172feb74e36d111285fa8cb',
    newDataList: [
      {
        link: '/products/deepak-test',
        price: 123.45,
        prid: '123456789',
        product_type: 'Indoor',
        quantity: 1,
        shipping: 'true',
        title: 'Deepak Test'
      }
    ]
  }
]

data ::
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-10-06 13:27:40,397 ERROR MongoTaskManagerPoolThread-1 MongoDao:236 - Failed record Index: 0, Record: UpdateOneModel{filter=Document{{siteId=910fb5db4172feb74e36d111285fa8cb, prid=123456789}}, update=Document{{$set=Document{{newDataList.price=123.45, newDataList.prid=123456789, newDataList.quantity=13.0, newDataList.shipping=false, newDataList.title=Test After g  Incremental}}}}, options=UpdateOptions{upsert=false, bypassDocumentValidation=null, collation=null, arrayFilters=null}} Retrying ...
```